# The provider in flutter doesn't change a screens

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I'm using a provider in flutter app to change screens in my app. Here is my main.dart file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:school_app/services/auth_service.dart';
import 'package:school_app/wrapper.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => AuthService().auth,
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: Wrapper(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Also this is my wrapper.dart file where the screens choose:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:school_app/screens/authenticate/auth.dart';
import 'package:school_app/models/user.dart';
import 'package:school_app/screens/school/home.dart';
import 'package:school_app/services/auth_service.dart';

class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context); 
    print(user.auth);
    if(!user.auth) return Auth();
    return Home();
  }
}
```

And it is my AuthProvider class:

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class AuthService {


   /* AuthUser _user(User user) {
    return user != null ? AuthUser(uid: user.uid) : null;
  }*/

AuthProvider auth = new AuthProvider();

  //sign in
  Future signIn(String username, String password) async {
    try {
      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      var dio = Dio();
      Response user = await dio.post('url', data: {
        'username': username,
        'password': password
      });
      if(user.data['success'] == false) return user.data['msg'];
      await prefs.setString('token', user.data['token']);
      auth.setAuth(true);
      print("SUCCESS");
    } catch(e) {
      print('Error ' + e.toString());
    }
  }

}

class AuthProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  bool _auth;

  AuthProvider() {
    _auth = false;
  }

  bool get auth => _auth;

  void setAuth(bool auth) {
    _auth = auth;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Also I made this variants of Wrapper widget, but it didn't work also:

```
class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = context.watch<AuthProvider>();
    print(user.auth);
    if(!user.auth) return Auth();
    return Home();
  }
}
```

And this one:

```
class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = context.watch<AuthProvider>();
    print(user.auth);
    if(!user.auth) return Auth();
    return Home();
  }
}
```

And when I call a function in AuthProvider class setAuth, nothing changed. Can you help me and find my mistake?

Comment: So I tried this and it worked when I call setAuth, not sure how you're calling the function tho. Also I'm not sure why you're doing it this way instead of injecting your service in your provider?

Comment: In AuthProvider file I have 2 classes: AuthService and AuthProvider. Also I`m calling function setAuth in AuthService: auth.setAuth(true);

Comment: I might be blind, but I still don't see the code in your examples where you're using the function. I see the code in your Service yea, but I don't see you calling it in your Widget. (Would also be kind of impossible to call it) Also imo the way you implemented it looks kind of weird/reversed. I would inject the service in your provider.